# Angular form validation with external data binding

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an Angular 4 form, but with the data tracked in an injected service (for reasons outside the scope of this question).

Each input looks something like...

```
<input name="..." [ngModel]='getVal(...)' (ngModelChange)='setVal(...)'>
```

...because there's extra functionality in those getters/setters.

That's working great, but I would also like to use the built-in validation. If I give my form a template reference variable...

```
<form id="..." #myForm="ngForm">
```

and look at the value of myForm, it's not tracking any of those inputs. I get that, I mean, I'm specifically telling it to track them elsewhere.

But how can I take advantage of the built in HTML5 validation? i.e. required and pattern

Answer (score 1):

You can use validation like this in your html. This is template based validation as per your requirement.
Submit button will not be active till all the fields are validated.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submitFunc()">
             <input name="name"  [ngModel]='getVal(...)' (ngModelChange)='setVal(...)'
               required pattern=""> //required pattern here
                <button [disabled]="!myForm.form.valid"  type="submit">Submit Form  </button> 
     </form>
```

You have to add required in your input field and specify pattern with a **regular exression**.

Comment: This is what I started with but it doesn't work, because the form reference variable isn't tracking the inputs, because the ngModel is pointing externally. The button is immediately not disabled. Unless there's some subtle difference I don't see.

Comment: try to bind your [(ngModel)] with model ts file..i.e. getter and setter should be defined in model file..